# Monero transfer privacy

Tags: security

If I want a transaction to be private, is it safe to follow a path like:

Coinbase > MorphToken (using Windows) > Official Monero (using Tails) > destination

Answer (score 1):

Level of privacy is a sliding scale and goes far beyond just Monero usage. E.g. you immediately lose some privacy by using a KYC exchange (as per your first step), which has nothing to do with the privacy features you get from Monero. For a higher level of privacy than what you have outlined, buy using a decentralized exchange (such as Bisq for example). Every centralized service you use, you lose some level of privacy.

If you are concerned with traffic analysis (from network providers for example), additionally use tor/i2p. This is because, for some people, they consider even being identified as simply *using* Monero is an unacceptable privacy loss.

All this said, the path you have outlined is certainly considerably more private than just using Bitcoin. The moment your Bitcoin are converted to Monero, it becomes ***considerably*** harder to trace.

It all boils down to your own acceptable risk profile.

Comment: Regarding your comment about traffic analysis I assume your referring to using morphtoken on Tor?

Comment: Partly yes. But what I'm trying to point out, this is more than just transaction privacy. Privacy is a sliding scale.